# Updating data in recyclerview

Tags: android

I am working on a project where the user enters the data to database at runtime and the recyclerview should get the data from database.Initially the recyclerview would be empty until the user enters data.But the problem is when the user enters the first item the recyclerview is updating and showing the first item.but when the user enters the second item the recyclerview is not updating it just shows the first item.

**My actyvity :**

```
public class Add_Details extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView personname,personmobile,Date;
    long id;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    EditText detailName,detailAmount;
    DatabaseHandler databaseHandler;
    AddDetails_adapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_details);
        databaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        detailName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Detail_name);
        detailAmount = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Detail_Amount);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.adddetail_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FFFFFF'>Add Details </font>"));
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        personname = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Detail_personName);
        personmobile = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Detail_personMobile);
        Date = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.adddetail_date);
        Intent received = getIntent();
        String pername = received.getExtras().getString("Name");
        String permobile = received.getExtras().getString("Mobile");
        id = received.getExtras().getLong("Id");
        String date = getDate();
        personname.setText(pername);
        personmobile.setText(permobile);
        Date.setText(date);            
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.adddetails_listView);
        upDateListview();
    }
```

**Update Listview method**

```
 public void upDateListview()
    {
        if (getDetails()!= null)
        {
            List<Details> pdetailslist = getDetails();
            adapter = new AddDetails_adapter(pdetailslist,this);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        }
    }
```

**Add details method : This method executes after user entering the data**

```
public void addDetails(View view)
    {
        if (!detailName.getText().equals(null)||!detailAmount.getText().equals(null))
        {
            String name = detailName.getText().toString();
            String amount = detailAmount.getText().toString();
            String date = Date.getText().toString();
            Details details = new Details(name,amount,date);
            databaseHandler.addDetail(details,id);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            upDateListview();
        }
        detailName.getText().clear();
        detailAmount.getText().clear();
        detailName.requestFocus();
    }
```

**getDetails method**

```
 public List<Details> getDetails()
    {
        if (databaseHandler.getDetails(id)!= null)
        {
            List<Details> list = databaseHandler.getDetails(id);
            return list;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

**getDate method :**

```
  public String getDate()
    {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE,dd-MMM-yyyy");
        String date = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
        return date;
    }
```

**My Adapter class**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by mrudu on 08-05-2016.
 */
public class AddDetails_adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AddDetails_adapter.View_holder>
{
    List<Details> list = Collections.emptyList();
    Context context;

    public AddDetails_adapter(List<Details> list, Context context) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public AddDetails_adapter.View_holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.add_detail_row,parent,false);
        View_holder view_holder = new View_holder(view);
        return view_holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(AddDetails_adapter.View_holder holder, int position)
    {
        holder.nametext.setText(list.get(position).getName());
        holder.amounttext.setText(list.get(position).getAmount());
        holder.dateText.setText(list.get(position).getDate());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public class View_holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        TextView nametext,amounttext,dateText;
        public View_holder(View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);
            nametext = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.adddetailRowname);
            amounttext = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.adddetailRowAmount);
            dateText = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.adddetailRowDate);
        }
    }
}
```

**Add details Method:**

```
  public void addDetail(Details details,long id)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DetaiInfo_Name,details.getName());
        values.put(DetailInfo_Amount,Double.parseDouble(details.getAmount()));
        values.put(DetailInfo_Date,details.getDate());
        values.put(DetailInfo_PId,id);
        sqLiteDatabase.insert(Detailinfo_TableName,null,values);
        sqLiteDatabase.close();
    }
```

*Than you....*

Comment: I was once trying to debug something similar. The issue wasn't that the view wasn't updating, but that the view was just big enough to show one item (but not two).

Comment: You should not create a new adapter every time you insert an entry into the database, just reuse the existing adapter and notify it of the changes. But a better solution is to use a Cursor Adapter and a Cursor Loader to automatically populate the list. See https://gist.github.com/skyfishjy/443b7448f59be978bc59

Comment: What does your `DatabaseHandler.addDetails(int)` do?

Comment: @JonathanDarryl  i just added the method to my question

Comment: @MallisettiMrudhuhas is `DetailInfo_PId` the primary key inside the db?

Comment: No it is not the Primary key..@JonathanDarryl

Comment: @TylerSebastian you are right dude but how can i solve this.

Comment: @MallisettiMrudhuhas show us your layout files

Comment: @TylerSebastian solved it.i set the height attribute to match parent.Thanks for your help

Comment: @MallisettiMrudhuhas ok but what other people have said as well is very important - you should not be recreating your adapter every time you insert an entry.